# Radon Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, radon-nikodym

> Given any two $\sigma-$finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on some measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ how do I compute $\dfrac{d\mu}{d(\mu+\nu)}$?

If $\nu<<\mu$ then I could have said that $\dfrac{d\mu}{d\mu+d\nu}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu}}$.

Thus I thought of using the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ w.r.t. $\mu$: $\nu=\nu_{ac}+\nu_s$ where $\nu_{ac}<<\mu$ and $\nu_s\perp \mu$. I guess that $\dfrac{d\mu}{d(\mu+\nu)}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{d\nu_{ac}}{d\mu}}$

Is my guess correct?

Comment: Have you tried verifying your guess, using the definition of Radon–Nikodym derivative? You could also try some simple examples. How about one where $\nu\perp\mu$, for example, $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, $\nu$ is counting measure on the integers?

Comment: Remember that you want to find $f$ such that 
$$\mu(A) = \int_A f \, d(\mu+\nu) = \int_A f \, d\mu + \int_A f \, d\nu.$$

Comment: If $\nu\perp\mu$ then let $N$ be the measurable set with $\mu(N^c)=0,\nu(N)=0$ then $\dfrac{d\mu}{d(\mu+\nu)}=1_N$